# SSRS: .... Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have this Expression:

```
= SUM(IIF(Fields!Numerator.Value = "ABC", 1, 0))
```

in a Text Box that I am using to get a count of how many rows have the value "ABC".

The report runs successfully - and the Text Box displays the correct number - but I get a Warning that says:

> [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the testrun 'Textbox55.Paragraphs[0]' contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Even though it is not stopping the report from running correctly [... warning - not Error] I still would like to know what Visual Studio sees as worth warning me about.

Plus . . . those warning messages bother me even to look at all the time ...
:D

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The data type of your Numerator column is probably a number in the underlying data source? In the expression you're comparing it to a string, that would cause the warning.

If you're using Visual Studio, it doesn't always clear the warnings after you fix the issue until you reopen it. So try that to confirm if this is warning is still applicable.

Comment: Thanks @StevenWhite. The data type of the Numerator Column is Varchar.

Comment: Thanks @StevenWhite. The data type of the Numerator Column is Varchar. What I mean to say in the Text Box expression is "when a row in the Numerator column has a value of "ABC" - then assign it  the numeric value 1 and then Sum() all those 1's in the Text Box [which is being used as a Sub Total for the # of occurrences of "ABC" in the Numerator column]. Is there a conflict between the data type of the Numerator [Details] column and the numeric subtotal text box?

Comment: @Talay The error appears to be between the column and the "ABC" string. Try this: `=SUM(IIF(CStr(Fields!Numerator.Value) = "ABC", 1, 0))`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the Warning anymore. Both your suggestion [using the CStr()], and my previous expr - are working now! Thanks!!

Comment: @Talay Great. It was probably lingering in VS from an earlier issue. Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after fixing the problem I received the Warning yet. After restart visual studio it's gone and there is no warning anymore.
I hope to help someone.